# Submitting POST data to a custom page template triggers a 404, why?

Tags: posts, page-template, forms

I've got a simple custom page template with a form on it. This page can process the form itself, so the entered data gets submitted there as well, using POST. Submitting the form, however, results in a 404 in my blog's regular theme (default template). If I leave out all of the data entry elements in the form, so I'll be submitting an entry form, it somehow works.

You can [use this code to reproduce the error](http://pastie.org/3224483) if you want to see for yourself.

Any suggestions as to what could be wrong are much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Here's the firebug report on what POST data is being submitted: http://i.imgur.com/cFKoV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

to:

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

I'm guessing that this is just a test case, but be sure that your final template has calls to `wp_head` and `wp_footer` in there.

Comment: Thank you so much! This problem really bugged me and I couldn't figure it out what was causing it. Really glad you've found out how to fix it! P.S: Just a test case indeed :).

Answer (score 4):

Are you using any of the wordpress reserved words in your html form? If yes that will give you a 404 page error when submitting.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms

Comment: Thanks for the link, but due to the prefix present in the code of my first post, I don't think I do - unless I'm misreading or forgetting something.